# undefined reference to my constructor

Tags: c++

I have a simple class which I cannot instantiate and I don't know why...
Please help me !

-------Test.cpp-------

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 #include "meteo.h"
 int main()
 {
    Meteo meteo;
 }
```

-------meteo.h---------

```
#ifndef METEO_H
#define METEO_H

class Meteo
{
    public:
    Meteo();
    int Get(int i);
    private:
    char *list[];
};

#endif
```

-------meteo.cpp--------

```
#include "meteo.h"

Meteo::Meteo()
{
    list[]("Sec","Venteux","Humide");
}

int Meteo::Get(int i)
{
    return list[i];
}
```

I get the error: "undefined reference to `Meteo::Meteo()'"

Comment: How are you building the program? It sounds like you're not compiling or linking `meteo.cpp`. (Once you fix that, you'll have plenty more errors to fix, since arrays don't work like that.)

Comment: Did you link the object file produced for `meteo.cpp` with your `Test.cpp`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you 4 correction. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Hello, I am building using g++. How can I link the file 'meteo.cpp' ?

Comment: @Yvain: The simplest way to compile and link both is `g++ test.cpp meteo.cpp`. Alternatively, you could compile each separately to an object file, `g++ -c test.cpp` (and for the other), then `g++ test.o meteo.o` to link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that the compiler issued an error when was compiling the constructor

```
Meteo::Meteo()
{
    list[]("Sec","Venteux","Humide");
}
```

and did not generate the object module.

This record

```
    list[]("Sec","Venteux","Humide");
```

is invalid.

Try to change the class definition like

```
class Meteo
{
    public:
    Meteo();
    int Get(int i);
    private:
    const char *list[3];
};
```

and define the constructor like

```
Meteo::Meteo() : list { "Sec","Venteux","Humide" }
{
}
```

The other reason might be that you did not include object module meteo in the project.

Take into account that this member function

```
int Meteo::Get(int i)
{
    return list[i];
}
```

is also wrong. The type of elements of the array is `const char *` not int.

Comment: That also sounds like the OP has a pretty crappy build system, that doesn't bail out on the 1st compilation error encountered.